# Does Facebook login kick off an event?

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, fbml

I have this on my page

```
<fb:login-button perms="publish_stream">Login with Facebook</fb:login-button>
```

But I want to know if there is a way that when a user clicks the login button, I can tell if they've successfully logged in or not, like if there's an event that Facebook throws me or something when that login window is closed, if the users attempt was successful or not.

I know I can check randomly in the app by making a request for the `me` object, and seeing if it comes back correctly, but I want it to be thrown right after that login window is exited (whether it is exited b/c a login was successful, or a user denied something).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can do it with this :)

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
  // do something with response.session
});
```

Comment: This. Check if `response.session` is defined to know if the user has completed the login or not.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for? http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/

Comment: Is there a way to do it from the fb:login-button though?